# web client can't access authorization header on response

Tags: cors, http-headers

I am doing a CORS GET call to my server and my web client can't see the authorization header on the response.

I am using axios library for the rest calls:

```
getReturn: function() {
  axios
    .get(
      "http://<cors url>/test",
      {
        params: {
          captcha: this.token,
          shipperEmail: this.shipperEmail,
          salesOrder: this.ereturn.invoice,
          consigneeEmail: this.ereturn.consignee.email
        },
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token
        }
      }
    )
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.token = response.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    })
    .catch(error => alert("something went wrong " + error));
},
```

When I checked chrome developer tools, both OPTIONS and GET requests are successful and GET response has the Authorization header I need:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://<cors url>
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
Vary: Origin
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3N1ZXJJZCI6Ii0xIiwiY291bnRyeSI6ImZha2UgY291bnRyeSIsInJvbGUiOiJTVEFGRiIsImFkZHJlc3MiOiJmYWtlIGFkZHJlc3MiLCJjaXR5IjoiZmFrZSBjaXR5IiwiaXNzIjoiZmFrZUNvbnNpZ25lZUBlbWFpbC5jb20iLCJza3VNYW5hZ2VtZW50IjpmYWxzZSwic3RhdGUiOiJmYWtlIHN0YXRlIiwidHlwZSI6IkNPTlNJR05FRSIsInBvcnRDb2RlIjoiZmFrZSBwb3J0IGNvZGUiLCJleHAiOjE1NjA0NzIyMTJ9.Z6HzgjPgg3sxJfxU9VCNIaTW6TDLnhNyrBDZqvAfhbM
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2163
Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2019 16:30:12 GMT
```

Client fails executing this:

`response.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];`

with error message `something went wrong TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

**QUESTION:** Why my code running in the client can't access the Authorization header flag showed by developer tools?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` was miss-configured on the web server:

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` contains the list of header flags accessible to the web client. So to fix this issue I just had to change:

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`

to

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Authorization`

In my tomcat configuration